# Property of integral and integrator. (NET June 2011)

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Consider the sequence of integrable functions $f_n(x)$ defined on the closed bounded interval $[a,b]$. Which of the following four options are correct?

1. If $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere then $\int_a^b f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$
2. If  $\int_a^b f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ then $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere.
3. If $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere and each $f_n(x)$ is a bounded function then $\int_a^b f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ .
4. If $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere and each $f_n(x)$ is an uniformly bounded function then $\int_a^b f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ .

Consider the function $f_n(x)$, on the interval $[0,1]$. Let $\{r_1, r_2, \dots\}$ is the enumerarion of rationals on $[0,1]$.

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{x = $r_1, r_2, \dots r_n$} \\ 0 & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$

Thus $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$, which is $0$ almost everywhere

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\0 & x \in [0,1] - \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]\end{cases}$$

But $\int_0^1 f(x)$ does not exists. Again eacu $f_n$ and $f$ are bouded and uniformly bounded. So 1,3,4, are false.

Consider another sequence of functions $g_n(x) = \sin(x), x \in [0,2\pi]$. $\int_0^{2\pi}g_n(x) dx = 0 $ $\forall n$. So $\int_0^{2\pi}g_n(x) dx \rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere but $g_n(x) \nrightarrow 0$. So 2 is false.

So all 4 are false. it is not so.

**Where is the mistake in these examples? Which options will be true and why?**

Thank you for your help. Second half of the question may be discussed. If it is , please give me the link.

Comment: If we're talking about the Lebesgue integral, $\displaystyle\int_0^1 f$ exists for the first example since it constant almost everywhere. Have you studied the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: I do not know dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: The theorem should be discussed in any text on measure theory. You'll probably see  uniform boundedness replaced with pointwise boundedness by a non-negatative integrable function - I don't know of a cleaner proof for the special case in 4).

Comment: @TimDuff I do not know measure theory. Please just tell me which topics should I know to solve the problem completely? domineted convergence theorem, pointwies boundedness, uniform boundedness and then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is definitely false.  Think of a sequence of rectangles with decreasing width and increasing height

2 is false.  The "typewriter sequence" is the standard counterexample.

3 is false, by the same example as 1.

4 is true (assuming that when you say each function is uniformly bounded, that means that there is a uniform bound for all the functions).  This is the bounded convergence theorem.

Comment: Thank you Euler for your interest to my question. So where is wrong with my example/

Comment: What is wrong with the example is that in fact the integral exists and is equal to $0$